# Play Setting maxInitialLineLength not working

Tags: scala, netty, playframework-2.4

I am working on a Scala API that may require occasional GET requests where the URL is longer than 4kb. I see that we need a setting `play.server.netty.maxInitialLineLength` set, and I tried setting this to 8192 (8 kb), but still fails:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes.
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.readLine(HttpMessageDecoder.java:670) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:184) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:485) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:na]
```

We are running play 2.4.8 right now. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're testing this locally and starting Play with the `run` command.

When doing this, the HTTP server settings in application.conf cannot be applied because the HTTP server is being started before the application.conf is being read (see also official [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration#HTTP-server-settings-in-application.conf)).

You have three options to get this working:

1. start the app in production mode, or
2. provide the configuration as a JVM parameter instead (`run -Dplay.server.netty.maxInitialLineLength=8192`), or
3. modify your build.sbt (`devSettings := Map("play.server.netty.maxInitialLineLength" -> "8192")`).

Comment: i tried suggestion number 2 and still can't get this to work (Play 2.4.6)